# What is a practical example of using Kiwi's KWCaptureSpy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, testing, kiwi

I'm having trouble understanding what a practical application of using Kiwi's `KWCaptureSpy` is. I could do something like this and have it pass:

```
 __block id successJSON;

  KWCaptureSpy *successBlockSpy =
      [HNKServer captureArgument:@selector(GET:parameters:completion:)
                         atIndex:2];

  [[HNKServer sharedServer] GET:@""
                     parameters:nil
                     completion:^(id JSON, NSError *error) {
                       successJSON = JSON;
                     }];

  HNKServerRequestCallback successBlock = successBlockSpy.argument;
  successBlock(@"JSON", nil);

  [[successJSON shouldEventually] equal:@"JSON"];
```

but that doesn't seem to actually be testing anything. The example in Kiwi's documentation doesn't help: https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/wiki/Mocks-and-Stubs#capturing-arguments

Has anyone had a good reason to use `KWCaptureSpy` in practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible scenario:

- you're consuming a RESTful webservice that allows you to update your profile by doing a `POST /user` with the details you want to update.
- you have a `HNKUser` class that declares an `updateFirstName:lastName:` method that calls the webservice
- you want to make sure that the method will send *only* the `firsName` and `lastName` to the server (e.g. it doesn't also send birthday and other details)

Supposing the method in discussion looks like this (I've omitted the completion handlers for simplicity):

```
- (void)updateFirstName:(NSString*)firstName lastName:(NSString*)lastName {
    // preparation code
    // ...
    [serverApi POST:@"/user" parameters:someParamsYouveBuiltInTheMethod completion:someCompletionHandler];
    // ...
}
```

then you might want to capture the second argument and make sure that it contains only the `firstName` and `lastName` fields, and also that those fields have the proper value.

As a note, spies are recommended to be used on mocks, and from your example I think yours is not.

Comment: So, if I was writing tests for `updatedFirstName:lastName`, I'd mock `serverApi` and place a `KWCaptureSpy` on the second argument of `POST:parameters:completion:` and set an expectation that `parameters` equals something `@{ @"first_name" : @"harlan", @"last_name" : @"k" }` ? 

the Kiwi documentation says `KWCaptureSpy`s are most useful for capturing blocks - and they include an example of then calling the captured block with canned data. is there a practical block example you know of?

Comment: The kiwi docs say that `Alternatively, and the most likely case`, and not that spies are `most useful`. I think the reason they phrased like this is because methods that don't expect blocks are easier to test via `should] receive:withArguments:]` than ones that expect blocks, as two identical blocks are not equal if they don't reference the same memory location.